Pac4j and Custom Forbidden page?
If a user has no permission, I got only this blank Forbidden page:

In the org.pac4j.jee.filter.SecurityFilter there is no unauthorizedUrl field to define the URL.
Is there any other possibility to set / redirect the user to a custom page, if the user has not the permission?
How can this be done?

Either you can override the 403 error page in your app or you can create your own permission Authorizer and throw a FoundAction exception with the wanted location (to break the flow and redirect to the expected error page).

Great, thank you

so this new FoundAction(applicationUrl) will be added in function isAuthorized or isProfileAuthorized Function from this class which I implement the interface "implements Authorizer" ?

Yes, this will "break" the flow to force the redirection to the wanted URL
